# how to make changes the value of one combobox when another changed in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, combobox

Actually i've two comboboxes.First one contains the countries list,and second one contains the states list.. if i click the particular country,the 2nd combobox should only show the states related to selected particular country only.

how to do this in Struts2 jsp form,thanks in advance.....

Comment: i don't know how to do this...

Comment: so far,i've used comboboxes for just displaying the items,if i click something in that combobox.. i don't know how to connect these two comboboxes......

Comment: What values do you want to change by the combobox?

Comment: @Roman C..I specified 3 countries in 1st combobox. <s:combobox label="SelectCountry" headerKey="-1" headerValue="SELECT"
list="#{'India':'India','Tamil eelam':'Tamil eelam','USA':'USA'}" name="country" label="Country"/>
also specified 6 states in 2nd 
<s:combobox label="Selectstate" headerKey="-1" headerValue="SELECT"
list="#{'TamilNadu':'TamilNadu','punjab':'punjab','yaazh':'yaazh','vanni':'vanni','New york':'New york','Washington':'Washington'}" name="state" label="State"/>....
if i click country(Tamil eelam) in 1st combobox,In 2nd combobox it should display(yaazh,vanni) only.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this of  status with javascript :

```
if( document.getElementById("combo..1").value =="1thvalue" ) {

document.getElementById("combo..2").value =="2thvalue"

}
```

Comment: @user2984034... thanks for the reply...                             Is it Correct?? if( document.getElementById("combobox1id").value =="CountryName" ) {

document.getElementById("combobox2id").value =="StateName"

}   Whether it will automatically change value in COMBOBOX2 as "StateName",if i click "CountryName" option in COMBOBOX1 ...        I tried as above u stated,it wont change in combobox2.... i don't know whether i did wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `jQuery`, try this:

```
<select id="country">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="state"></select>

var data = ["state1", "state2", "state3"];

$("#country").change(function(){
    // get data with $.ajax ..
    var option;
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        option += "<option>" + value + "</option>";
    });
    $("#state").empty().append(option);
});
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jaiwo99/fgt5R/

Comment: The question is about comboboxes not a select dropdown.

Comment: It's UI tag [combobox](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/combobox.html).

Comment: @RomanC what's the difference, i don't think it will render something else than `select`

Comment: @Jaiwo99,@hari thanks for the replies......it works,when i running online     But, i need it in struts2 jsp tag using <s:combobox>  Even i'm running above code in netbeans or just save as html file,2nd combobox not changing when 1st changed

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
    <select id="country">
       <option>India</option>
       <option>Pak</option>
       <option>UK</option>
    </select>
   <select id="state"></select>
```

Jquery

```
 var data = [
{"India":"tamilnadu"}
,{"Pak": "lokur"},{"UK" :"london"}
];  // Json data

 $("#country").change(function(){
     var option;
     $.each(data, function(index, value){
     $.each(value,function(countr,stat){
       var x=$("#country").val();
         if(x==countr){
            $("#state").empty();
            $("#state").append("<option>"+stat+"</option>");
          }
       });
    });
});
```